# Adding CSS to osssearchresults.aspx

Tags: sharepoint-online, css

I made several design changes to my SP online site.
Everything went smoothly 'till I encountered the search page *osssearchresults.aspx*

I'm aware that *osssearchresults.aspx* is a server page and doesn't let you edit in browser.

However, light visual changes(CSS) need to be made in order to keep the same pattern throughout the site (functionality will stay unchanged).

My question is, how to accomplish that requirement? What do I need to change?
Must I use SPD for that?

All of this happens in a site level and not a site collection.

Thank you,

Comment: Create your own search center is the only option.

Comment: Hi Amal, How do I do that? and will the same functionality that I have now remains? Search Center will show queries from site only or the site collection?

Answer (score 0):

To add CSS, you must create an Enterprise Search Center and use that instead of the osssearchresults.aspx, then you can add CSS to any of the result pages.

http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/office365-sharepoint-online-enterprise-help/manage-the-search-center-in-sharepoint-online-HA103994122.aspx